# Mapping issue with mmap and multiple processes

Tags: c, exec, multiprocessing, shared-memory, mmap

First time using mmap and I have a program that creates a file and shares it so another program can access it.  Here is how I have it initialized in my main:

```
    //Main.c
    file = open(FILE_PATH, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);
    result = lseek(file, FILE_SIZE-1, SEEK_SET);
    result = write(file, "", 1);
    map = mmap(0, FILE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, file, 0);
```

Note I have omitted the error checking to minimalism the code length.  After the open is successful I am writing an array of about half a million ints to the file and then forking multiple instances of a sort program to sort parts of the array.  Each child process gets passed a separate part of the array (Sindex and EIndex are always changing).

```
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    if ((proccessIdArray[i] = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork");
    } else if (proccessIdArray[i] == 0){     
        execl("mysort", FPATH, FSIZE, ARRAYSIZE, SIndex, EIndex, (char *)NULL); 
        perror("exec"); 
        exit(0);
    } 
}
```

Here is how I am opening the file in my sort program:

```
    //Sort.c
    file = open(argv[0], O_RDWR);
    map = mmap(0, fileSize, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, file, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) { // It is failing here for child processes 5-10
        close(file);  
        perror("Error mapping file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    .
    .
    // sorting code
    .
    .
    munmap(map, fileSize);
    close(file);
```

It works fine for running up to 4 processes however anything beyond 4 returns an error:

```
Error mapping file: Invalid argument
Child 18225 status 0x100.
Child 18226 status 0xb.
Child 18227 status 0xb.
Child 18229 status 0xb.
Child 18230 status 0xb.
Child 18228 status 0xb.
```

I am assuming I am either creating or opening the file incorrectly to accommodate for all the read/write requests but I am not sure what needs to change.  Any insight into how to solve this problem?

*Edit*:
Turns out the fileSize in the Sort.c file is getting 0 from processes 5-10 which is why it is giving the invalid arguments call but I still do not know why it is passing fileSize 0 for those processes.